# Source Version 'T' in VSTS build

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines

Occasionally when triggering a new build (for a TFVC repo) the "Source Version" becomes "T" and the build is not picked up by any agent. It remains in the "Waiting for an agent to be requested" state. New builds triggered from then work fine:

[image: VSTS Build Source Version]

Nothing happens when browsing to "T".

Does anyone know what this could be?

Comment: When you click on "T", does it open the Code Explorer in the web portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because someone specified "T" as the "Source Version" when queue the build.
[image]

When "T" is specified as the source version, the build task will execute "tf get /version:T" command that will get the latest version of your source code. Refer to [tf get command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/get-command) for details:

> /version:versionspec
>
> Specifies the maximum version, or the minimum and the maximum
> versions, to display in the history data. The default is /version:T
> (the latest version).

Comment: Thanks the answer, but I can't imagine how we could have mistakenly supplied such a value for the Source Version several times across 3 different build definitions. It hasn't happened since but I will report back if it does.

Comment: This has just happened again. I will ask my team if anyone else has experienced the same issue.

Comment: @davenewza Do you know who queued that build and the steps?

Comment: I did. I don't know if anyone else has experienced it yet. I will ask the team.

Comment: @davenewza So you just click "Queue build..." and then click "OK"?

Comment: Correct. With "Source Version" empty.

Comment: @davenewza What's build agent you use? Hosted or your own?

Comment: We are using our own.

Comment: @davenewza Then another possibility is that the build process hangs when obtaining the latest version. I see that behavior a few times with scheduled build definition. The source version displays as "T" for a few seconds when the build is triggered and then changes to the latest version. You can go to the "_diag" folder in build agent folder to check the logs.